# error with array, lodash outputing -1 from index.Of()

Tags: javascript

I know the issue is with the array , index.Of() is grabbing -1 which means its grabbing nothing... would i need to rebuild my array to get the correct value?
testingsom.js

```
const lo = require('lodash')
const Holiday = require('./Holidays')
let Holidayslist = 
    [{
        Name: 'New Years Day' , 
        date: new Date('January 1 2023')
    } ,
    
    ,{
        Name: 'Christmas' ,
        date: new Date(' December 25 2023')
    } 
    ,{
        Name: 'Canada Day' ,
        date: new Date('July 1 2023')
    }]
currentTime = Date.now()
for(const Holidays_obj of Holidayslist) {
    console.log(   Holidays_obj.Name + ' is  ' + (Holidays_obj.date - currentTime ) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)  + '  ' +'Days away ')
    }
random_person = lo.sample(Holidayslist)
//console.log(random_person)
//console.log(Holidayslist[1])
indexArray = lo.indexOf(Holidayslist.indexOf('Christmas'))
console.log(indexArray)
```

Holidays.js

```
class Holiday {
    constructor(date, Name) {
    this.name = Name; 
    this.date = date; }

}

module.exports = Holiday
```

Comment: That's not how you use lodash [indexOf](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#indexOf).

Comment: `lo.indexOf()` needs two arguments: the array to search, and the thing you're searching for in that array.

Comment: You could use [findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findIndex)

Comment: ditch lodash and just use vanillaJS methods. Better off in the long run and less overhead

Answer (score 1):

you're basically writing lo.findIndex(-1) since HolidaysList.indexOf("christmas") as parameter already returns -1.

[Lodash Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/#findIndex)

you pass the array and a callback which executes on every item of the array.

```
lo.findIndex(Holidayslist, holiday => holiday.Name === "Christmas")
```

Comment: Did you mean findIndex rather than indexOf?

Comment: yes. fixed. my bad